# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a problem when I try to connect to MySQL database from my Spring Boot application. My application.yml contains following configuration

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/wortschatz;
    username: "bot"
    password: "bot"
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

When I try to use user "bot", I am getting an error "`Access denied for user 'bot'@'127.0.0.1' to database 'wortschatz;'`". At the same time I am able to login and query the database using MySQL Workbench.

The most confusing part is that I specified 'root' user credentials in my application.yml and it didn't work with error "`database 'wortschatz' not found`"

I suppose, I am missing something on MySQL side. But what exactly? Permissions seems to be Ok (see below)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a silly typo in `url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/wortschatz;`. There is redundant semicolon at the very end of configuration string. It should be just `url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/wortschatz`